# Why my Jquery "click Function" execute after page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
$("form").before().click(function () {
    $('.woocommerce_checkout_login p').toggleClass("show");
});
```

I want add the class just after click, but when I reload the page it add for a few seconds.

Comment: Not sure you're using [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) properly, might be worth reviewing its doc

Comment: Your use of `before()` is suspect, and adding a `click` handler to a `form` is very odd too

Comment: Was exactly the before(). I change a few stuffs and works.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a `before()` in your chain?

What you need is:

```
$("form").on('click', function() {
    $('.woocommerce_checkout_login p').toggleClass("show");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I removed and work. Why the before element was making this happens?